# ASP.NET Script Include Read Permissions Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, include

I have an ASP.NET MVC App with a Razor page (call it Sample.cshtml) which includes a JS script file in the Head section as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.example.net/Errors/utils.Version4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(exact names have been changed to protect the innocent). The application is on a Shared Hosting site and through the site's Control Panel I have set IIS Permissions on the Errors subdirectory to Allow Anonymous Access for SSL and Enable Read Permissions for SSL while I have DISALLOWED Allow Anonymous Access and Enable Read Permissions.

The issue is this: when I log on to my app and Authenticate (using Forms Authentication) and the controller loads Sample.cshtml, the js file cannot be read. If I do a View Source and click the link in the Script tag I see some error HTML that indicates I don't have permission to read the resource, Error Code 403.2. HOWEVER, if I type the src URL into the Address Bar I can download the JS file fine and view the text in my browser.

Why would I have Read Permissions if I use the Address Bar but NOT have read permissions when the src is called from my page script include? I've experimented a bit and if I also check Enable Read Permissions (so that Read Permissions are enabled for both SSL and non-encrypted http) the problem goes away.

I'm sure there's a logical answer that I'm just not sophisticated enough to discern but I'm desperate to fix this (and desperate to learn) so any information would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm new to SO. What exactly is accept, does it mean I appreciate a response or accept a response as the answer? I looked in the FAQ but didn't see anything about it.

Comment: Hi Norman,

Can you run a tool like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/) to snif the traffic going to and from the machine where you're making these requests?  It should be trivial to determine whether the javascript file is being sent over SSL.

Thanks,
Clay

Comment: Clay, I have Fiddler and did experiment with it but I'm not too skilled with that program (I have other skills, just not that one). However, my hosting company told me that the "SSL" version of the rights I mentioned above referred only to "Shared SSL", which gave me some additional information I'm working through now. I will try to leverage Fiddler and learn how to use it properly. Thanks very much for trying to help me out, ultimately it will boil down to why my JS files can end up being downloaded unencrypted by simply appending a ":80" to the host name.